# Accessing content of CookieContainer() in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, cookiecontainer

Ok, I've thrown in the towel and turned to those who might be in the know.  I've searched the net, tried some examples but I'm no closer to pulling out data from my cookie container.

When I debug my code I can see the entry/value I'm after on my variable at: CookieContianer > Non public members > m_domainTable > {domain URI} > Value > list of entries

There is an entry in there called JSESSIONID.  All I want to do is get at that specific entry so I can use it's assigned value.

Can anyone shed any light how I can easily go about it?

Many thanks.

==== 
Example of how I'm making my request (note RequestItem is passed in from another method):

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestItem.RequestUri);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

.... some additional code here building up a web request

var formResponse = (HttpWebResponse)formPost.GetResponse();

... some additional logic to check the headers to see if authentication was successful

 requestItem.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;

 //This call to the requested protected resource which uses the cookiecontainer from the authenticat

 var passRequest = (HttpWebResponse) requestItem.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your cookie key/value pair key is `JSESSIONID` and you are trying to get the value of that key in your `ASP.NET` application; you can do something like below

```
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["JSESSIONID"].Value;
```

Comment: Hi Rahul,  thanks for your reply.  I'm working on a web api project and making a call using HttpWebRequest.  Because I'm working with RTC I'm having to authenticate first of which passes a cookiecontainer back to my main call for the web resource I'm requesting.  So I wasn't able to use the example you kindly posted as is.

Comment: @Sulphy, does your `requestItem.CookieContainer` contains the cookie value? Do you mean whan you call the method `requestItem.GetResponse();` it automatically tries to read the cookie value. Sorry I can't offer much help cause I myself confused as to how you are trying to read the cooki value.

Comment: Hiya.  By copying the CookieContainer across from the bit of code that handles the forms authentication I can request a protected resource.  This works OK, but I think RTC (the REST api I'm talking to) is a bit funny and wants another specific header to be present.  When I debug and hover over my requestItem variable the properties/attributes for the CookieContainer are shown.  I can navigate through and find some values listed, one of which is the JSESSIONID entry.  The problem I have is that I've not a clue how I can grab this data and pull it out of the CookieContainer using code.